# CA2229 Rules with a Model

Tags: catel

I was doing Code Analysis on my project and I got some warning on rule [CA2229](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms182343.aspx)

Considering this snippet

```
[Serializable]
public partial class Split : ModelBase
{
    private double? fx;

    public int? Currency { get; set; }

    public double? Fx
    {
        get
        {
            return this.fx;
        }
        set
        {
            this.fx = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Fx);

        }
    }
}
```

should I implenent the constructor as suggested?

```
protected Split(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{

 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the serializable part is only required when using binary serialization. In that case it's best to create 2 constructors:

```
public Split()
{
    // Use when instantiating yourself
}

public Split(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    // Used by serialization
}
```

Comment: Bu You do so every time you've a class that inherits from modelbase And a [Serializable] attribute?